# python, limmiting function running time

Tags: python, multithreading, timing

I have a function that depends on the internet and downloads files, however sometimes the download time is too long or the sending request processes is failing.I wanted to know how can I set some-thing like a timer for the function, and if it exceeds the time (lets say a minute) to rerun the function from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `signal` for time out cases

First set the signal handler with `signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)`

To set the time for the signal alarm use `signal.alarm(seconds)`

If the request to download is taking too long, i.e more than the seconds specified in alarm, the handler will be called upon

You could check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html).